# Python Variable based on number of files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following problem:

I put in one variable the output from `os.lostdir` - this are `.txt` files. The number of files can vary each day. I want to assign every `.txt` file to a variable with the name of the `.txt` file.

Is this possible?

For example:

I have three `.txt` files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`. I want to assign the contents of `a.txt` to a variable `a`. However, the file names can change every day. Is there a way to do this in `python`?

Comment: What should happen if the file's name is something that can't be a Python identifier, for example `in.txt`, `or.txt`, `def.txt`, `this filename has spaces in it.txt`, `10_9_2018.txt` ...?

Comment: Generally you should use a dict for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Kevin good point. I guess OP could just use some character in the variable names to differentiate or something.

Comment: You should reconsider your approach for this problem altogether. Dynamic variable names are almost always a glaring design flaw.

Comment: Thank you guys - i was doing it with a dictionary.